# await is only valid in async function - if else function

Tags: react-native

I check if there is such data in the firestore with (if (docSnapshot.exists)). I need to call await function when it goes inside else, but in this way I get an error "await is only valid in async function". How can I use the await function inside if else?

```
drawRoad = async (userLatitude,userLongitude,BranchLocationLatitude,BranchLocationLongitude,minPrice,shippingPrice) => {
    try {
let userid = (this.props.UserStore.UserId).toString()
             await  firestore().collection('Tracking').doc(userid).onSnapshot(docSnapshot => {

 if (docSnapshot.exists){  
...
}
else {
...     
      let rsp=await fetch(url)
      rsp=await rsp.json() }
}, err => {
 
  console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
});
    

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      console.log("hata_componentDidMount HomeMap")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
else {
...     
      await fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => do what you want with the response like setState, console.log it or whatever)
.catch(err => console.log(err))     
}
```

Maybe try to tell the function to be async like this.

```
async function drawRoad(){

  await fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
```

Comment: No, it will not work that way first of all await firestore (). Collection ('Tracking'). Doc (userid) .onSnapshot (docSnapshot => {
 you have to enter the function